# the Software that came with my Camera is for Windows and Mac. What to do?

Tags: 14.04, camera

I have a Olympus SP-720UZ camera and i want to install the software that came with the camera, on the olympus website, there are only options for windows and mac, how do i install it on ubuntu ?

Comment: yes, it works :D 
Thanks a ton for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ubuntu, you don't need the software that came with the camera. As you found out most camera manufacturers don't provide a software for Linux. They don't need to, as Ubuntu has the needed software already installed.

Just connect the camera and it should be recognized. If that does not work, or if you prefer, you can also take the SD card out and put it in a card reader.

Either way, Ubuntu has built-in software called [Shotwell Photo Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) to recognize and import the pictures into your computer. Then you can use Shotwell to view edit, and share the pictures.

Hope this helps

Comment: A annoying problem I have encounter with Ubuntu, is that often it won't recognise my sdcard... Fortunately, Shotwell Photo Manager comes to help when the sdcard is plugged in the camera, but then, it will be mounted non writeable... disallowing the user to use the sdcard for something else that read only device. I really like Ubuntu, but those things needs to be addressed somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user68186. I'm already following this bug that was filed ~1 year and some of us we need to reboot with sdcard to be able to use it, otherwise it doesnt fully work. The maintainers have worked a lot with this and have fixed it for broad range of model, but unfortunately, in my case, I have to deal with the reboot workaround. 

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I am sorry to learn about the problems. Unfortunately I am just an user, and I can't help with the bug.